# What is the signal that indicates which neurons Schwann cells should myelinate versus which should remain unmyelinated?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

Schwann cells are neuroglial cells that produce myelin in the peripheral nervous system.

However, not all axons are myelinated - some will remain unmyelinated.

There must be some signal that indicates which cells are to be myelinated - what is it?

Comment: Are you asking what the signal is that makes some neurons remain un-myelinated? "Unable to form" seems to imply that they *should* be myelinated but somehow fail to be, rather than that some should be myelinated and others should not. Or are you asking why myelination is not necessary for all neurons?

Comment: I m asking that why schwann cells donot form myelin sheath around axon in non myelinated neurons?

Comment: Are you asking what the signal is that makes some neurons remain un-myelinated, or are you asking why myelination is not necessary for all neurons?

Comment: Yes I m asking what the signal is that makes some neurons unmyelinated?